# Error when I trying mock a repository

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I tried mock a repository and return the same object that was saved.

This is my code snippet:

```
 public TransactionType createTransactionType(TransactionTypeEnum type) {
        TransactionType transactionType = new TransactionType();
        transactionType.setStatus(type.code());
        transactionType.setDescription(type.name());

        return transactionTypeRepository.save(transactionType);
 }
```

I tried mock something like this:

1.

```
public TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder doSave(){
            Mockito.when(this.target.save(Mockito.any(TransactionType.class)))
             .then(new SaveMock<>())
             .then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
            return this;
}
```

2.

```
public TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder doSave(){
                Mockito.when(this.target.save(Mockito.any(TransactionType.class))).then(new SaveMock<>());
                return this;
}
```

3.

```
public TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder doSave(){
                     Mockito.when(this.target.save(Mockito.any(TransactionType.class))).thenReturn(new TransactionType());
                    return this;
}
```

4.

```
  public TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder doSave(){   

    Mockito.when(this.target.save(Mockito.any(TransactionType.class))).then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());

        return this;

  }
```

My builder class

```
public class TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder {
    private final TransactionTypeRepository target;

    private TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder() {
        this.target = Mockito.spy(TransactionTypeRepository.class);
    }

    public static TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder create(){
        return new TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder();
    }

    public TransactionTypeRepository build() {
        return this.target;
    }

    public TransactionTypeRepositoryMockBuilder doSave(){
        Mockito.when(this.target.save(Mockito.any(TransactionType.class))).thenReturn(new TransactionType());
        return this;
    }

}
```

I received this error:
 *_java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(ILjava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;_* 
What I did wrong?

Comment: what's you mockito version?

Comment: It's Mockito 2.8.47

Comment: I find your input utterly confusing. Why do you *setup* your mocks within methods called doSave()? Thus: please step back and show us a real [mcve] - including the essential parts of your production and test case code. What you are showing here simply doesn't make much sense (imho).

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the feedback. I updated it.

Comment: Did my answer helped? did you find other solution?

Answer (score 3):

There was an [update](https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2016/10/11/mockito-2.1/) in mockito-2.1. The method `getArgumentAt()` takes different parameters. So you must have inconsistency in your mockito jars.

> when(userDeviceService.save(any(UserDevice.class)))
>       .then(invocation -> invocation.getArgumentAt(0, UserDevice.class)); Now:
>
> when(userDeviceService.save(any()))
>       .then(invocationOnMock -> invocationOnMock.getArgument(0));

Comment: There was a real change in method signature. See https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.9/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html vs https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html

Comment: Updated my answer